# How to solve Source control operation failed: svn: E155007?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

When I am using force build to build my project it is showing, Last build is successful, but in the Recent build report it is showing.

**ERROR:**

```
BUILD EXCEPTION 

Error Message: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: E155007: 'C:\MaxLeadPro\LivePortal' is not a working copy
```

I am new to Cruise Control.net, can you please help me anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `svn: E155007: 'C:\MaxLeadPro\LivePortal' is not a working copy` indicates that your configured working directory is not a subversion working copy.

You may want to check why this directory does not exist anymore and if `autoGetSource` is true.

Take a look at the configuration of your [Subversion configuration in CCNet](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Subversion_%28svn%29)

Comment: AutogetSource is set true

Comment: Please update your question with your project configuration and debug log of CCNet around this error.

Comment: Process command: C:\Program Files (x86)\svn-win32-1.8.1\bin\svn.exe log -r "{2013-08-30T12:09:46Z}:{2013-08-30T13:00:22Z}" --verbose --xml --no-auth-cache --non-interactive

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in CCNet communicating to svn 1.7
use CCNet 1.8.4, it has been fixed
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/versions/10

svn changed the layout of their working copy
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng